# ReactJs where to put reusable logic

Tags: reactjs, structure

I am coming from a AngularJs background and trying to learn ReactJs, all the component, reduces, action thing seems quick clear, but one thing for me is missing. What is the alternative for angularJs service/factory, where do I put reusable logic, for now I just put them in separate modules like example:

```
export default {
    loggedIn: () => {
        var accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        if (!accessToken)
            return false;
        return true;
    },

    getToken      : () => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        if (token !== null)
            return token;
    },
    getBearerToken: () => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        if (token !== null)
            return 'bearer ' + token;
    }
}
```

And then just require it in. If this is not one of the ways, then where should it be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! Just make a module and require it.
 I usually add my http related files in a directory called 'services' or 'api'. You can also create a directory called 'helpers' ant put logic content to avoid repeat yourself.

Comment: Jest is awesome and performs very well with React! But I'm sure you know ;-)